# How to set to select drop down list from back end C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have one `DropDownList` and `Button` on my page.

After I select the dropdownlist and click the button, it will redirect to same page, and It has to show in dropdownlist what I select before redirect

Here is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            //ASPxGridView1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Request.QueryString["ReqID"] != null)
                ddlRequestNo.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["ReqID"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("GPApproveCheque.aspx?ReqID="+ddlRequestNo.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
    }
```

When I see the url, It is showing what is choose on first time

**for example**

On my drop down list if I have value

```
111
222
333
444
```

1.Once I select **222**, I can see in the url bar like below

```
http://localhost:55047/GPApproveCheque.aspx?ReqID=222
```

2.Still drop down list is showing 111

3.When I select second or third time a different options from dropdown, it will show in the url the same old one **222** and dropdownlist never change **111**

**Update**

When I try this below code, it throws **System.NullReferenceException**

```
ddlRequestNo.SelectedIndex = ddlRequestNo.Items.IndexOf(ddlRequestNo.Items.FindByText(Request.QueryString["ReqID"].ToString()));
```

Which it returns null for `ReqID`. How it is possible, Because, I am passing parameter like `"GPApproveCheque.aspx?ReqID="+ddlRequestNo.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()`

Page load function execute before it receive parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Page_Load should be as below because you are redirecting to page on button click and so page loads again and your value assignment should be done in !IsPostback block.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        if(Request.QueryString["ReqID"] != null)
            ddlRequestNo.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["ReqID"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlRequestNo" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="111" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="222" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="333" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="444" />
</asp:DropDownList>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlRequestNo.SelectedIndexChanged += DdlRequestNo_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
private void DdlRequestNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri+ "?ReqID=" + ddlRequestNo.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());
        }
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            ddlRequestNo.SelectedIndex = ddlRequestNo.Items.IndexOf(ddlRequestNo.Items.FindByText(Request.QueryString["ReqID"].ToString()));
    Response.Redirect("GPApproveCheque.aspx?ReqID="+ddlRequestNo.SelectedItem.Text.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: it throws nullreference Exception bro

Answer (score 0):

You can try the same method Shah has recommended but if Query string is causing an issue you can change it to using ViewState to store the drop-down list selection and then rebind it on PageLoad.

Replace Request.QueryString["ReqID"] with ViewState["ReqID"] and reassign it on postback